# Is there a collection in C# with single key multiple items with different types(string, int etc)

Tags: c#-4.0

Something which acts as a lookup by key. I am trying to create collections which can be identified by a key and its properties retrieved.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered just creating a type to represent those "items with different types"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of types:

```
IDictionary<int, Tuple<string, int, DateTime>>
```